# The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $

Tags: json, angular, typescript, type-conversion, boolean

I'm trying to send a request from Angular front to asp.net API server.
The form to be submitted is defined as:

```
export class SaleToUpdate {
    id: number;
    shipped: boolean;
    shipDate: string;
    returned: boolean;
    returnDate: string;
}
```

**markup and code**

```html
<mat-grid-tile [colspan] = "2" [rowspan] = "1">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="shipDate" matInput placeholder="Ship Date">                                         
         </mat-form-field>                
         <div class="radio-group ml-3">
              <mat-radio-group formControlName="shipped" required (ngModelChange)="shipped">           
                    <mat-radio-button value="false">No</mat-radio-button>
                     <mat-radio-button value="true" class="ml-4">Yes</mat-radio-button>
              </mat-radio-group>
         </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

The onSubmit() method

```
onSubmit() {    
   if (this.salesService.saleForm.valid) {
      let sale: SaleToUpdate = this.salesService.saleForm.value;  
      console.log(sale); 

      this.salesService.updateSale(sale.id, sale).subscribe(res => {
         console.log(res);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
   } 
}
```

Therefore, basically, my purpose it to send the form data (`SaleToUpdate` class) to the backend server.

**DTO on server-side**

```cs
using System;
namespace API.Dtos
{
   public class SaleUpdateDto
   {      
       public int Id { get; set; }          
       public bool Shipped { get; set; }
       public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }       
       public bool Returned { get; set; }
       public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
   }
}
```

From the console, I got the error

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.shipped | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 274." when click onSubmit from the client.

I noticed the values for `shipped`&`returned` from the form are **string** datatype rather than **boolean** datatype

Can anyone please help me out with any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

format your `boolean` fields from the `Class`

```
let sale: SaleToUpdate = this.salesService.saleForm.value;  

sale.shipped = sale.shipped === 'true' ? true: false;
sale.returned = sale.returned === 'true'? true: false;
```

Comment: Complains for the conditions "sale.shipped === 'true' ", and "sale.returned === 'true' " as the "conditions will always return 'false' since the types 'boolean' and 'string' have no overlap."

Comment: What I made it work eventually as below: data.shipped = this.salesService.saleForm.controls['shipped'].value === 'true' ? true : false;
      data.returned = this.salesService.saleForm.controls['returned'].value === 'true' ? true : false; The reason why this works could be that these values may have to be directly from the Form controls other than from the form values after ISale being applied, I guessed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to format the form data before submitting. Just create a new data object and parse the value from string to boolean. Something like this

```js
onSubmit() {    
    if (this.salesService.saleForm.valid) {
      let sale: SaleToUpdate = this.salesService.saleForm.value;  
      console.log(sale); 
      //this is where to parse object
      var data = {
            id = sale.id,
            shipDate = sale.shipDate,
            shipped = sale.shipped === 'true' ? true: false //this line does the trick
            ....
       }
      this.salesService.updateSale(sale.id, data).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    } 
  }
```

Hope you find this helpful

Comment: Complains: No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'id'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.

Comment: Do you have any comment on what I made to above answer?